# Angular 5 dependency injection (service to test file)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am learning about marble tests and when following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/testing-ngrx-effects-3682cb5d760e) I reached a point where my simple test looks like this:

**user-effects.service.spec.ts**

```
imports ...
describe('User Effects', () => {
    it('basic test', () => {
        const source = cold('--a', { a: { type: LOGIN } });
        const effects = new UserEffectsService(new Actions(source), ?? );

        const expected = cold('--b', { b: { type: LOGIN_SUCCESS } });
        expect(effects.login$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
});
```

However my UserEffectsService needs 2 arguments

**user-effects.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffectsService {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private userService: UserDataService) {
    }
    ...
```

Maybe I could pass there a new instance of UserDataService, but UserDataService needs 2 more arguments etc. and there would be a long chain. I couldn't find any solution for injecting a dependency without a constructor. Any tips how to deal with this case are appreciated, thanks.

@edit
**anyone? :D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the injections into your service.

```
const actionsMock = {};
const userServiceMock = {};
```

Then, put all the variables and functions used in your current service, in your mocks.

For instance, let's say you use the `getAllUsers` function from your user service : then add it to your mock :

```
const userServiceMock = {
  getAllUsers: () => Observable.of([/* array of users */])
};
```

Now, you can create any number of objects you want :

```
const instance = new UserEffectsService(actionsMock, userServiceMock);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this.

In your `beforeEach` you can inject services like this:

```
let service = TestBed.get(UserDataService)
```

then when you create new Effect Instance you can just pass instance of service.

```
const effectService = new UserEfectsService(action,service);
```

If you have multiple services you can do something like this:

```
let [service1, service2, serviceN] = [Service1, Service2, ServiceN].map(TestBed.get);
```

Comment: I think the purpose is to avoid using the testbed here

Comment: Avoid testbed for injecting effectsservice. I would say other dependecies are ok.

Comment: No I mean, you're not forced to use the test bed, you can only test the functions of your class. I think it is what he's trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yep, I just want to test if LOGIN_SUCCESS is executed after LOGIN, but @DušanStanković this solution isn't working, because there is no provider for UserDataService